# Sonar WebService API - resources endpoint returns no metrics

Tags: java, web-services, rest, sonarqube

I'm using **Sonar 4.5** and I'm trying, by accessing the API, to get all the **violations** for a project... for this I'm trying to use the **resources** endpoint with my project's key. The response contains the basic info but not all the other metrics (violations, coverage etc...). This is what I'm getting:

```
    {
        "id": 582,
        "key": "myGroupId:myProject",
        "name": "madfox",
        "scope": "PRJ",
        "qualifier": "TRK",
        "date": "2014-10-23T15:10:11+0100",
        "creationDate": "2014-10-06T09:58:21+0100",
        "lname": "myProject",
        "version": "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
        "description": ""
    }
```

And I was trying to use another endpoint that might help but nothing useful so far. Is there anything I can do for the endpoint to return more info? Can the violations be gathered in a different way?

UPDATE:
I've tried all the resources endpoint variations:

```
api/resources/index
api/resources
api/resources?resource=myGroupId:myProject
api/resources?resource=myGroupId%3AmyProject
```

They return the project's info, or all the projects when the resource param is not specified, but none of them contains the metrics

I'm also using the **sonar-ws-client** and that returns the same thing when I use the ResourceQuery class for the find method.

UPDATE2: **Steps to reproduce**:
Use a rest client, like Postman or just the browser since they are GET endpoints with following urls:

**http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources**

**http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources?resource=org.apache.activemq:activemq-parent**

Comment: Can you please update your question with the URL you are calling?

Comment: @Mithfindel Of course, sorry, question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to add the metrics that you want to appear in your response, e.g `&metrics=violations,tests`: http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources?resource=org.apache.activemq:activemq-parent&metrics=violations,test

Comment: Oh, ok... I tried with metrics but I thought it should return everything and the ids are just for filtering... at least this is what the api suggests. It's very confusing. Anyway, thanks a lot!